# For non-modal/auxiliary verb, is the non-3rd person singular present form always the same as the base form?

Tags: verbs, conjugation

The Penn Treebank Parts of Speech tag set differentiated between the base form of verbs (VB), and the non-3rd person singular present form (VBP).

Consider the following cases, with the different uses of rise:

> **base form:** The share price will rise.
>
> **non-3rd person singular present:** The share prices rise.

In both cases the forms are the same.

All the examples I have seen of verbs where that is not true, are with verbs that can be considered (by some definition) to be modal and/or auxiliary. Such as: *be, am, are, is, was, were, being, can, could, do, did, does, doing, have, had, has, having, may, might, must, shall, should, will, or would*

**Are there examples of words from outside my modal/auxiliary list, of  non-3rd person singular present forms that are different from their base forms?**

I would particularly appreciate referenced answers, sourcing any statements about their nonexistence/rarity.

Comment: This is not a suitable question for ELU; my adding 'it is best not to regard _be_,  _have_, and _do_ as auxiliaries in some usages' may confuse a learner. Certainly the verb _will_ as in 'she willed her paintings to charity' is not an auxiliary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Neither is *willed* a modal verb in that example.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Really necessary? '... the modal auxiliaries are can, could, may, might, must, shall, should, will, and would.' (ODO)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth what do you mean by   "not a suitable question [as] ... may confuse a learner?". surely advanced topics/confusing topics are definitely ontopic here? (But not on ELL perhaps, which *is* for learners)

Comment: A learner surely quickly comes across 'Verb Conjugation & Spelling:
We form the present tense using the base form of the infinitive' [for main verbs] [ [Grammar.cl](http://www.grammar.cl/Present/Simple.htm)]

Comment: Are you saying the question is too basic (off-topic as general reference), and/or the answer is too complex (as it may confuse learners)?

Comment: Sorry I don't get why *can, have, do* etc are exceptions? The only exception here is *BE*. The only reason to say that a modal such as *can* is different is perhaps just because they cannot be proven to have a *base* form.

Comment: @Araucaria mostly I find thinking about modal verbs confusing, and thus they make poor examples. I have other reasons to exclude them from what I am working on right now though (they tend to have no antonyms except for adding the contraction n't or not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the OP's question is: 'yes'. Mostly. The only English verb which differs from its plain form outside of the third person, is the verb *BE*. The verb *BE* is usually an auxiliary verb.

However, the verb *BE* can also be regarded as a lexical verb in sentences such as:

- If you don't be careful ...

Notice that the sentence above uses *DO* as a dummy auxiliary even though *BE* is present. Because of this there might possibly be cases where it is impossible to distinguish between *BE* as a lexical or auxiliary verb. However, I know of no such cases. Lexical *BE* rarely if ever rears it's head as a tensed verb. Arguably the positive polarity version of the phrase above is:

- If you be careful

Here we are still using the plain form of the verb, not the present tense. There is a strong case therefore that tensed *BE* is always an auxiliary. This would mean that there are no exceptions to this rule.

However, there is one more issue that might put a spanner in the works here. The verbs *BEWARE* and *USED* have no present tense form in current usage. *BEWARE* is only ever used in the plain form because it only occurs in imperative constructions. The verb *USED* as in *I used to smoke*, is only used in the past tense. It could be argued, therefore, that these verbs do not have any present tense form that is identical to the base or plain form.

You can read more about lexical versus auxiliary *BE* in the reference grammar *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston & Pullum, 2002.

Comment: For the reference of others, the key statement: "...verbs other than be this form [non-3rd person singular present tense] is synchronized with the plain form." is on page 84, first paragraph under heading 1.6, of The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Huddleston & Pullum, 2002.

Answer (score 1):

Your list is a bit lop-sided as modal verbs have no infinitive, only one form for present tense and one form for past tense, with the exception of must, that normally is not used in past tense.
And it is wrong to include to have and to do. These verbs have the same form for the infinitive and for present tense (to have/I have, to do/I do).